# Using Backbone.js Models/Collections with static JSON

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm trying to learn Backbone by diving right in and building out a simple "question" app, but I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to use models and/or collections correctly. I've added the code up to where I've gotten myself lost. I'm able to get the collection to pull in the JSON file (doing "var list = new QuestionList; list.getByCid('c0') seems to return the first question), but I can't figure out how to update the model with that, use the current model for the view's data, then how to update the model with the next question when a "next" button is clicked.

What I'm trying to get here is a simple app that pulls up the JSON on load, displays the first question, then shows the next question when the button is pressed.

Could anyone help me connect the dots?

**/questions.json**

```
[
  {
    questionName: 'location',
    question: 'Where are you from?',
    inputType: 'text'
  },
  {
    questionName: 'age',
    question: 'How old are you?',
    inputType: 'text'
  },
  {
    questionName: 'search',
    question: 'Which search engine do you use?'
    inputType: 'select',
    options: {
      google: 'Google',
      bing:   'Bing',
      yahoo:  'Yahoo'
    }
  }
]
```

**/app.js**

```
var Question = Backbone.Model.Extend({});
var QuestionList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Question,
  url: "/questions.json"
});

var QuestionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#question').html()),
  events: {
    "click .next" : "showNextQuestion"
  },
  showNextQuestion: function() {
    // Not sure what to put here? 
  },
  render: function () {
    var placeholders = {
      question: this.model.question, //Guessing this would be it once the model updates
    }
    $(this.el).html(this.template, placeholders));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is evident, in the current setup, the view needs access to a greater scope than just its single model.  Two possible approaches here, that I can see.

1) Pass the collection (using `new QuestionView({ collection: theCollection })`) rather than the model to `QuestionView`.  Maintain an index, which you increment and re-render on the click event.  This should look something like:

```
var QuestionView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
     // make "this" context the current view, when these methods are called
     _.bindAll(this, "showNextQuestion", "render");
     this.currentIndex = 0;
     this.render();
  }      
  showNextQuestion: function() {
     this.currentIndex ++;
     if (this.currentIndex < this.collection.length) {
         this.render();
     }
  },
  render: function () {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.collection.at(this.currentIndex) ));
  }
});
```

2) Set up a [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) and call `router.navigate("questions/" + index, {trigger: true})` on the click event.  Something like this:

```
var questionView = new QuestionView( { collection: myCollection });

var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "question/:id": "question"
    },

    question: function(id) {
        questionView.currentIndex = id;
        questionView.render();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the examples! So, in this situation, where is the advantage to using a collection at all? I mean, couldn't I do the same thing with my own ajax call and caching the result? All of the examples I see for them and models seem to focus a lot on saving data to the server. Is that the only use case?